# How to wrap data-equalizer with content_tag

Tags: ruby, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to wrap div-equalizer-watch inside content_tag but the div-equalizer-watch is getting print **(
{:"data-equalizer-watch"=>"", :class=>"list_users"}**). Can someone guide me where I am doing wrong

Below, is the HTML which I am trying to write in rails helper with content_tag & capture tag

```
<a href="/ussers/profile" target="_blank">
  <div class="list_users" data-equalizer-watch="">
    <h2>Cost</h2>
  </div>
</a>

content_tag :a, href: "/ussers/profile", target: '_blank' do
  capture do
    concat (content_tag :div, :"data-equalizer-watch" => "",:class => 'list_users')
    concat (content_tag :h2, 'Cost')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution

```
content_tag :a, href: '/ussers/profile', target: '_blank' do
        capture do
          concat (content_tag :div, nil, :"data-equalizer-watch" => "", :class => 'list_users' do
             concat (content_tag :h2, title)
          end )
        end
      end
```

Took reference from this [link](https://gist.github.com/bunnymatic/4222736)